# Pronunciation of unstressed 'я'?

Tags: произношение

Is there a pronunciation rule for unstressed **я**?

I remember being told that it was closest to English *i*, for example, as in `десять` but this doesn't always hold.  It seems that at the end of a word it can be either *a* or *ya*: `бояться`, `сегодня`.

At the beginning of a word: `являться` is it *yi*, *i* or *ya*? There is clearly a disagreement between [this](http://www.forvo.com/search/%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F/) and [this](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F) speaker.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In standard pronunciation, unstressed **я** is reduced to /ɪ/. See, for example, [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vowel_reduction_in_Russian) for a good explanation of the subject.

However, one thing that should be kept in mind is that letters **е**, **ё**, **ю**, **я** mean different things after different letters:

- After consonants, they are not yotized and denote /э/, /о/, /у/, /а/ (not taking reduction into account, here); in addition, the preceding consonant is palatalized (becomes soft): *десять* /'dʲesʲɪtʲ/.
- In other cases (after vowels, soft and hard sign, and in the beginning of a word), the vowel is yotized: *ясный* ‘clear’ /'jasnɨj/.

In your case, it's yotized and reduced, so, based on my own (hopefully pretty standard) pronunciation:

> являться /yɪ'vlʲat͡sa/

Comment: There is no [t͡s] in this word, it is just [ts] here.

Comment: @Anixx, it depends. Some people properly pronounce this cluster, some people reduce it.

Comment: Why is the last unstressed я in являться not reduced to /ɪ/  and why doesn't it palatize the preceding "С" ?

Comment: My understanding is that the verb endings -ться/-тся have special pronunciation /t͡sa/, cf: http://www.russianforeveryone.com/Rufe/Lessons/Course1/Introduction/IntrUnit10/IntrUnit10.htm — there is probably a good explanation why which must be linked to the evolution of the language.

Answer (score 4):

In Moscow speech (which is the base for the standard pronunciation used on TV broadcasts and such), the initial unstressed `я` would be yotized and reduced to `ɪ` (near-close), something between `е` and `и`.

Some dialects (mostly Northern) reduce it further to `i` (close), like the sound denoted by `и`. This is OK in most words and would probably not be perceived at all by the majority of the audience, but could result in a hiatus in words like *яичница* which is considered undesirable in Russian speech.

Some dialects to the south of Moscow exhibit *yakanye* (яканье). Those dialects would only slightly reduce the sound to a near-open `æ` or even won't reduce it at all (leave an `a`). This is considered dialectal.

There is a rhyme to mock a person who uses *yakanye*:

> А у нас в Рязани
>   Грибы с глазами
>   Их едят (*ядять*),
>   А они глядят (*глядять*)!

When telling this rhyme, vowels should not be reduced at all, and the word `едят` should start with a yotized `a` (as open as possible). Also, to mock the other aspects of the dialect, `Г` should be pronounced fricative (`ɣ` rather than `g`), and the final consonants `т` should be softened (palatalized).

Answer (score 1):

The pronunciation of *я* depends on whether it is preceded a consonant or not. Generally, it is pronounced as [ja] [йа], however if it is preceeded by a consonant it softens the consonant and is pronounced as [a]. For example, in *бояться* the first я is pronounced as [йа], because it is preceded by a vowel, but the second я is pronounced as [a] (and the syllable is pronounced like сьа), because it is preceded by a consonant.